# Adding CastCompanionLibrary to a project - Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cast

How would one go about adding the CastCompanionLibrary to a project in Android Studio. I read the README.md and the pdf in the repository but neither detail how. Any help getting this added to my project would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This project might help you:  https://github.com/sgehrman/CastVideos-android

Comment: There are also some notes at the bottom of the CastVideos-android sample here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Doug, I have had the hardest time getting any of the samples to build properly in android studio. The one referenced in your first project works great, and answers my question as well. Go ahead and make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project on Github was forked from the Google Cast demos and rebuilt for Android Studio:  https://github.com/sgehrman/CastVideos-android

Answer (score 2):

The CastCompanionLibrary now has gradle build files, so you can import that into Android Studio directly, or reference that from another project (see an example of that in CastVideos-android project).